# Problem with the function of pressing a button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I set a button with a function and it gives me an error:

> end1.html: "20 Uncaught ReferenceError: reload is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

How do I fix this?

```
<body>
    <button id="Reload" type="button" class="myButton" onclick="reload()"> reload </button>

<script>
function reload(){
    if(localStorage.a==6){
        Location.href="page2.html";
    }
    if(localStorage.a==8){
        Location.href="page3.html";
    }
    if(localStorage.a==10){
        Location.href="page4.html";
    } 
 } 
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: If your code looks like that `reload` will be called. You will, however, receive a _"SecurityError: The operation is insecure."_ warning which is probably down to the way you're trying to access local storage.

Comment: Any "fatal" errors in `reload()` function will make it undefined. Since uppercase `L` on `Location.href` makes function broke. That is, js respects case-sensitive.

Comment: With the HTML you are showing, **that error will definitely not occur**. There must be deviations between your actual HTML, and the HTML you present in your question.

Comment: @GetSet those typos will not make the function undefined.  It just won't work properly, and probably give a reference error.

Comment: Yeah @Andy I was looking at it while typing comment, seems OP is *not* showing actual code.

Comment: Is this *all your code*? I can't understand why this error is happening. What browser are you using? IE 7?

Comment: Perhaps OP you have an open tag before this script gets defined. Like a script tag or another that is not closed before your current script you do post here in your question gets defined. That is your script for this function could be nested (erroneously due to faults on other opening tags) in code you dont show, which makes it undefined on that order.

Comment: `<script> ... </script>` should work in any open tag to be clear. But since what you show makes no sense to reproduce the error you show, something must be amidst in the actual code sequence in your actual source.  .... This is why I always advise in not pointing us to where you think the error is, because you cant solve it and as such better to just show your complete source, since someone (other than you) can find problem, hence your need to ask here in first place,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix is to use the built-in `addEventListener()` function in JavaScript, instead of using the `onclick` attribute in HTML.

To use this feature, you can delete the `onclick` attribute on your `<button>` element in your HTML, so that it will look like this.

```html
<button id="Reload" type="button" class="myButton">Reload</button>
```

Then, you can add the following function in your JavaScript. Add the following lines below your `reload()` function.

```js
const reloadButton = document.querySelector("#Reload"); // Get the button from the DOM

function reload() {
  // Function code...
}

reloadButton.addEventListener("click", reload); // Alternative to 'onclick'
```

The listener will wait for a `click` event, and when it occurs, it will run the `reload()` function (without a `ReferenceError`).

---

Also, in your `reload()` function, you need to change `Location` to `location`. This is because JavaScript is case-sensitive, and it will throw an error if you leave `Location` as-is.

```js
// Before
Location.href;

// After
location.href;
```

Comment: Thank you!!!
Your answer helped me a lot !!